# Opening standalone multiple tabs in gnome-terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome, tabs

I am trying to find a way to open multiple telnet session to multiple hosts with scripts.

I thought of using `gnome-terminal` command with options to open tabs and execute the commands as follows,

```
gnome-terminal --disable-factory -e "telnet x.x.x.x 2055" -t "host_55" --tab --disable-factory -e "telnet x.x.x.x 2057" -t "host_57" &
```

I have refereed something from [here](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/gnome-terminal/).

With this I am able to open new terminal with multiple tabs and each executing the `telnet` to the host.

The problem is that, If I close the telnet session, then terminal tab itself getting closed.

I want it to run as a stand-alone just as how we do it.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to keep the terminal open, you could add something like `"telnet x.x.x.x 2057; bash"`. This will launch the bash after telnet closes, keeping the terminal open.